# How to merge Datasets representing matrices with named rows/columns?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I am working with square (non-symmetric) matrices with named rows and columns.  The data I receive is sometimes messy and rows/columns may come in various permutations.  I usually need to semi-manually put every matrix into a canonical permutation before I can work with it.  I'd rather never have to think about permutations and not even define a canonical one, just index the matrices using the names of their rows/columns.

I was hoping that `Dataset` would be helpful here, and I made `Dataset` objects like these:

```
ds1 = Dataset[<|"a" -> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, "b" -> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 0|>|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ds2 = Dataset[<|"a" -> <|"b" -> 1, "a" -> 5|>, "b" -> <|"b" -> 1, "a" -> 2|>|>] (* I used a different permutation on purpose *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What is the simplest way to merge these together to obtain the following?

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> <|"a" -> {1, 5}, "b" -> {2, 1}|>, "b" -> <|"a" -> {3, 2}, "b" -> {0, 1}|>|>]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of merging with `List` I will usually need to merge with other operations, e.g. `Plus`.  Once I've built a dataset with `List` it's easy to do that though.

Comment: To clarify, I'm asking if there's a nice and simple way to do this.  I can do it in an ugly way.  I can then package up that ugly way into a merging function and just use it.  But then Dataset didn't help me too much, I might as well have created my own optimized labelled table data structure.

Comment: Is this simple enough? `Merge[Normal/@{ds1, ds2}, Merge[#, Identity] &] // Dataset`

Comment: @Rojo if you use operator forms, it can get (in my view) a bit cleaner: `Merge[Merge[Identity]] @ Map[Normal] @ {ds1, ds2}`

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon definately. Combining all, `merge[level_] := 
 Nest[Merge, Identity, level]@*Map[Normal]@*List /* Dataset`. And `merge[2][ds1, ds2]`

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm deliberately waiting to see what use cases are most common before I devise a general Dataset-merging operation. Feel free to propose something if you think you've nailed the semantics of what such a thing should be.

Comment: @Rojo nice. But the tricky part here will be dealing with intermediate levels that *aren't* associations.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon After I've worked with this for a few days, I'll let you know what sorts of operations I used the most, if that helps decide.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon One (simple) generalization to `Merge` would be to allow level specifications. I repeatedly find myself using something like `Nest[Merge, fun, n]` where `n` is the desired depth and `fun` is the desired lowest-level merging function.

Answer (score 5):

Since the question stems from working with matrices with named rows and columns I think the answer below is relevant. My answer does not use or deal with Dataset objects, but with sparse matrices with named rows and columns.

In the last few years I have used a lot the R base library Matrix that has implementation of sparse matrix objects and efficient computations. To the sparse matrices from the [Matrix R library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) one can assign and retrieve row and column names with the functions `colnames` and `rownames`. Sometimes I miss this in Mathematica so I started a Mathematica package that implements similar functionalities. The package does not use RLink, it has purely Mathematica language implementations.

The `RSparseMatrix` objects of this package can deal with the permutations of row and column names. (Note that the package is not finished and in some functions the row and column names are ignored.)

[This document](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/RSparseMatrix.pdf) has demos/tests. (Arithmetic operations, matrix products, joining, profiling, etc.)

[This blog post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/rsparsematrix-for-sparse-matrices-with-named-rows-and-columns/) has a neat application example.

**Load**

This loads the package from GitHub:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/RSparseMatrix.m"]
```

**Creation**

Create a `RSparseMatrix` object with array rules (like for `SparseArray`) and names of rows, columns, and dimensions:

```
rmat = MakeRSparseMatrix[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {4, 3} -> 3, {1, 4} -> 4},
    "ColumnNames" -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, "RowNames" -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
    "DimensionNames" -> {"U", "V"}];
```

Show the created matrix:

```
rmat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The creation can be done with a `SparseArray` object:

```
rmat = ToRSparseMatrix[SparseArray[rmat], 
   "ColumnNames" -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, "RowNames" -> {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, 
   "DimensionNames" -> {"U", "V"}];

rmat // MatrixForm
```

**Permutations**

Here we permute the matrices:

```
MatrixForm[rmat[[RotateLeft[RowNames[rmat], 2]]]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm[rmat[[All, RotateLeft[ColumnNames[rmat], 2]]]]
```

[image]

```
MatrixForm[
 rmat[[RotateLeft[RowNames[rmat], 2], RotateLeft[ColumnNames[rmat], 2]]]]
```

[image]

**Converting to SparseArray**

At some point it is better to convert to an inherent data structure of Mathematica:

```
SparseArray[rmat[[All, RotateLeft@ColumnNames[rmat]]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Given the name of the package, it would be a good idea if you spelt out that it does not depend on RLink.  RLink tends to be a bit slow and doesn't play well with parallelization, so it can be a disadvantage.  But this package doesn't use RLink, that's good.  Also: it might have been better (and might have led to more exposure for the package) to start a separate post for this. You can ask a question and answer at the same time, e.g. "How can I work with labelled sparse arrays?", answer: "Here's a package and here's how it works". Then add an additional answer here pointing to that thread.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok thanks, these are good points. I didn't think that the name of the package might imply the use of RLink. And yes, I was thinking that my answer is a little out of place for this question...

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use `MapIndexed`.  For example:

```
MapIndexed[{#, ds2 @@ #2} &, ds1, {2}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

or, to add matching entries:

```
MapIndexed[# + ds2 @@ #2 &, ds1, {2}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]