# With "named row" nested Datasets: How to Select or Filter rows by row key with criteria from another Dataset?

Tags: dataset, associations, filtering

After some calculations and grouping I have a `Dataset` similar to the following form:

```
data = Dataset@<|
   "A" -> Dataset@<|
      "x" -> <|"c1" -> 22, "c2" -> 34|>,
      "y" -> <|"c1" -> 1, "c2" -> 18|>,
      "z" -> <|"c1" -> 11, "c2" -> 2|>
      |>,
   "B" -> Dataset@<|
      "x" -> <|"c1" -> 13, "c2" -> 4|>,
      "y" -> <|"c1" -> -2, "c2" -> 5|>,
      "z" -> <|"c1" -> 33, "c2" -> 12|>
      |>
   |>
```

[image]

The row names are items of a groups located in another dataset with form similar to the following:

```
groups = Dataset@{
    <|"Name" -> "Group1", "Id" -> "x"|>,
    <|"Name" -> "Group1", "Id" -> "y"|>,
    <|"Name" -> "Group2", "Id" -> "z"|>
   }
```

[image]

I would like to `Select` (or the equivalent) the named rows in the sub-datasets of `data` that have row keys in `"Group1"` of `groups`. This is to be in a `Manipulate` or `DynamicModule` where the user will select the group name from `groups` and have final calculations made and displayed from that group in `data` across the rows.

I can get a list of the ids for the a group with:

```
Normal@groups[Select[Function[{row}, row["Name"] == "Group1"]], "Id"]
(* {"x", "y"} *)
```

As I understand `data[All, op]` should run operator `op` on the sub-dataset in each row of `data`. I planned on using `KeyValueMap` in a `Select` for `op` like so.

```
data[All,
 Select[
  KeyValueMap[
    Function[{key, value},
     ContainsAny[{key}, 
      Normal@groups[Select[Function[{row}, row["Name"] == "Group1"]], "Id"]]
     ], #] &]
 ]
```

However, this is returning empty sub-datasets.

[image]

How do I get the following as my result? I've had a look at `JoinAcross` but it doesn't seem to be for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: Fyi, the inner `Dataset` are typically unnecessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, we want to `Select` the `groups` where the `"Name"` is `"Group1"`, which we do like so:

```
In[1]:= groups[Select[#Name == "Group1" &] /* Lookup["Id"]] // Normal
Out[1]= {"x", "y"}
```

From there, we want to call `data` on our `Dataset` of keys; note that this won't work if we just pass it a list of keys instead. I'm actually not sure precisely where this behavior is documented; it comes from having nested `Dataset`s, though.

```
In[2]:= data[groups[Select[#Name == "Group1" &] /* Lookup["Id"]]]
```

[image: resulting Dataset]

There are many ways of accomplishing this; another way depends on `GroupBy`:

```
data[GroupBy[groups, First -> Last]["Group1"]]
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. `data[{"x", "y"}]` errors as expected so how is `data[groups[Select[#Name == "Group1" &] /* Lookup["Id"]]]` working as it essentially is passing the same thing.  May you explain how this is working in the answer?

Comment: +1 Wow, a tip o' the hat for jamming so much cleverness into a single query.  Kudos for figuring out that `Dataset["x"]@Dataset[<|"x" -> <|"a" -> 1|>, "y" -> <|"a" -> 2|>|>]`, will cause the inner expressions like `<|"a"->1|>` to be treated as plain data instead of as operators.  But also using this to flip the query/data relationship: mind-blowing.  I wonder how stable such subtle behaviour will be between releases?

Comment: @WReach Is your comment to be taken as a warning that this method should not be used?

Comment: @Edmund No, I would use the method if it fills your needs.  My question may be rhetorical but it is genuine (as is my praise).  I am only musing upon the subtle changes in `Query` behaviour that we have seen with each 10.x release to date.  I'm hopeful that such changes are becoming less frequent.

Answer (score 5):

Probably using only Dataset objects is a requirement. The solution shown here is in the same vein as the one given for [How to merge Datasets representing matrices with named rows/columns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56710/how-to-merge-datasets-representing-matrices-with-named-rows-columns/). I.e. this solution does not use Dataset objects but [RSparseMatrix](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/rsparsematrix-for-sparse-matrices-with-named-rows-and-columns/) objects.

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/RSparseMatrix.m"]
```

The dataset elements converted to RSparseMatrix objects:

```
rmats = ToRSparseMatrix /@ (Normal[Values[data]]);
MatrixForm /@ %
```

[image]

Here is a conversion of groups into an association (I assume it can be done in a better way):

```
grouping = 
 Association[
  Map[{#[[1, 1]] -> #[[All, 2]]} &, 
   GatherBy[Values /@ Normal[groups], #[[1]] &]]]

(* <|"Group1" -> {"x", "y"}, "Group2" -> {"z"}|> *)
```

Now the subsetting with row names corresponding to a group is easy:

```
Map[#[[grouping["Group1"]]] &, rmats];
MatrixForm /@ %
```

[image]

This solution is fairly close to a solution of the same problem in R. I would have given an R/RLink solution, but the conversion of datasets into R's data frames did not seem to be easy.

Comment: An interesting solution (+1) but, as you noted, I'd much prefer to stick with `Dataset` throughout rather than introduce a dataset-esque structure.

Comment: @Edmund Right, I understand. It is just this problem and my solution would fit very well in the discussions I had at WTC 2015 about `Dataset`s and Mathematica vs R.