# Combine two matrices of unequal dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a 11x11 matrix and a 23x23 one. The 23x23 is a null matrix and I need to insert the 11x11 matrix in the null matrix for a specific position of the element 6,6 in the first matrix like this:

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

aaaaaaaaaaa000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

00000000000000000000000

So element 6,6 at the first matrix is inserted at the position 6,6 at the second matrix. The elements of the first matrix are **not** all the same, it is a generic set of data. I need to be able to put the element 6,6 in any position of the second matrix, assuming that it won't overflow the limit of 23x23. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
n=ConstantArray[0,{23,23}];
m=RandomInteger[1,{11,11}];

With[{i=10,j=10},
  ReplacePart[n,Select[
      Flatten@MapIndexed[(#2-{6-1,6-1}+{i-1,j-1})->#1&,m,{2}],
      AllTrue[First@#,Between[#,{1,23}]&]&
    ]
  ]
]//MatrixForm
```

It puts the element $6,6$ in position $i=10,j=10$.

Comment: Thanks, Kenny. I ended up doing like this: newM = Sum[
   Sum[SparseArray[{Band[{(3*j + 1), (3*i + 1)}] -> M}, {n, n}], {i, 
     0, (d - 1)}], {j, 0, (d - 1)}];, so I can also sum all the combinations I need   at the same time :p

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you want to insert the 11x11 into the 23x23 at position {6,6}

```
n = ConstantArray[0, {23, 23}];
m = RandomInteger[1, {11, 11}];
```

First make a copy of `n` if you want to keep it (you could work directly with `n` if it was not needed).

```
newMatrix = n;
```

Next equate specific elements of `newMatrix` with `m`.

```
newMatrix[[6 ;; 16, 6 ;; 16]] = m;
```

Here is what it looks like

```
newMatrix // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

Since the matrix into which you wish to insert is all zeros you can simply [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html) the input matrix.  I'll use dimensions 5x5 and 11x11 to keep the examples manageable.

```
SeedRandom[0]

input = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 7 & 0 & 8 & 2 & 1 \\
 5 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 7 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 1 \\
 2 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 5 \\
 8 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

This embeds into an 11x11 array starting three rows down and one column in:

```
PadRight[input, {11, 11}, 0, {3, 1}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 7 & 0 & 8 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 5 & 8 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 8 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

You can also use [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html) but you'll need to calculate the dimensions:

```
ArrayPad[input, {{3, 3}, {1, 5}}]

(* same output *)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason to post this answer is that although it is longer than a [dedicated answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145978/34008), its code shows the systematic use of the package [`RSparseMatrix`](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2015/10/08/rsparsematrix-for-sparse-matrices-with-named-rows-and-columns/) for these kind of tasks.

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/RSparseMatrix.m"]

mat0 = ConstantArray[0, {23, 23}];
mat1 = RandomInteger[1, {11, 11}];

rmat0 = ToRSparseMatrix[SparseArray[mat0], 
   "RowNames" -> Map[ToString, Range[Dimensions[mat0][[1]]]], 
   "ColumnNames" -> Map[ToString, Range[Dimensions[mat0][[2]]]]];

rmat1 = ToRSparseMatrix[SparseArray[mat1], 
   "RowNames" -> Map[ToString, Range[Dimensions[mat1][[1]]]], 
   "ColumnNames" -> Map[ToString, Range[Dimensions[mat1][[2]]]]];

SetRowNames[rmat1, 
  Map[ToString, (6 - 1) + Range[Dimensions[mat1][[1]]]]];
SetColumnNames[rmat1, 
  Map[ToString, (6 - 1) + Range[Dimensions[mat1][[2]]]]];

rmat1 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
rmat2 = ImposeColumnNames[
          ImposeRowNames[rmat1, RowNames[rmat0]], 
          ColumnNames[rmat0]];
rmat2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Also see these answers:

1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145785/34008 ,
2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96351/34008 .